# Secure client server channel

Tags: security, ws-security

I'm building an application that needs to establish a secure connection between a client and a server, providing web services.
I need to guarantee authenticity for both (client and server), the server will also be handling the client authorization to access the data and files.
If thought to do it using an EKE-like algorithm to authenticate both, but these relies on a previously shared secret.

I could use the client password as the shared secret, but I would need to securely establish that password upon the client sign up, in this case I would need a secure channel, and authenticate the server (the client needs to know which server he is registering into).

I would rather avoid using a CA to provide certificates with the server public keys, because its a lot of extra code for just one small job, and it wouldn't be the best solution, because I would just have to trust the CA.

Ultimately this is to let the client send (client-)encrypted files to the server and share them.

Any alternatives that I'm missing out?

Tl;Dr How to stablish a secure client/server channel, authenticating the server, without CA, know public keys, or previous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSL/TLS offers wide choice of authentication mechanisms, including pre-shared secrets, OpenPGP keys etc. So you can go for SSL and avoid reinventing the wheel.

Also you can sign and encrypt individual data messages (again using OpenPGP as a variant).